# How to run Android JUnit tests from multiple projects in eclipse?

Tags: android, junit, robotium

I'm wondering how to run multiple projects containing Android JUnit Robotium test from eclipse at once... 
I hope someone could help.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I was caught up in the similar situation. I used command line to run my test. You can use the following commands

For a single Test

```
adb shell am instrument -e your class -w your package/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

For all your Tests

```
adb shell am instrument -w your package/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can run JUnit tests across multiple projects using the open source Classpath Suite.

Create an Eclipse project which contains a dependency on all the projects you want to test.
Write a suite:

```
@RunWith(ClasspathSuite.class)
public class MySuite
```

Take a look on this article: [Roger Rabbit - JUnit Tests Runner Across Multiple Projects](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/690079/Roger-Rabbit-JUnit-Tests-Runner-Across-Multiple-Pr), it includes a step by step example and a code sample.