# Running JUnit tests from multiple projects in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

It's possible I'm losing my mind, but this morning when I upgraded to Eclipse Kepler I tried to run unit tests for multiple Eclipse projects at the same time and failed. I selected multiple projects, opened the right-click menu and the "Run as..." options were gone.

"Damn Kepler!" I thought and fired up my old Juno install to convince myself the behaviour had changed. However, it didn't work in there either.

I'm now questioning my sanity over whether this was ever truly possible. [Many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525757/how-to-run-android-junit-tests-from-multiple-projects-in-eclipse) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137479/run-junit-tests-from-several-projects-conveniently-fast-in-eclipse) Stack Overflow  questions and other [sites](http://www.ryanlowe.ca/blog/archives/001227_eclipse_how_to_run_all_tests_in_multiple_projects.php) suggest this is a difficult, if not impossible task. However, I'm so sure I was doing this in the recent past that it's left me a little rattled.

So... has this even been possible, either in Kepler or Juno? Can anyone suggest a popular plugin that might have enabled that feature (which I incorrectly assumed to be default behaviour)?

*Background: I have a multi-module Maven project managed through m2e and expected I could select several of the projects and run all the unit tests*.

Comment: Do you still have run configurations available? If so, just create a configuration for it and run that.

Comment: @JREN Sorry, yes, the "Run configurations..." option is still there. But if I go that route, I can only run the tests for one project, not multiple projects.

Comment: There should be a radio button available that says "Run all tests in the selected project, package or source folder:" If you have 2 projects selected it should run all unit tests for both. It works for me at least :-/. I'm using Eclipse Juno

Comment: @JREN, can you describe more how you're doing that? The Select... button there doesn't allow multiple selection, you can only select one project, package or folder.

Comment: Corresponding eclipse bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=111126

Answer (score 6):

You can perform JUnit tests across multiple projects using [Classpath Suite](http://johanneslink.net/projects/cpsuite.jsp).
In general all you need to do is:

1. Create an Eclipse project depending on all the projects you want to test.
2. Write a suite:

   @RunWith(ClasspathSuite.class)
   public class MySuite

Take a look on this article: [Roger Rabbit - JUnit Tests Runner Across Multiple Projects](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/690079/Roger-Rabbit-JUnit-Tests-Runner-Across-Multiple-Pr),
it includes a step by step example and a code sample.

Answer (score 3):

If you, instead of using the context menu, use the keyboard shortcut (default = `Alt-Shift-X` `T`), you will get the following dialog:

[image]

This is a hint about why Eclipse doesn't show the option in the menu – it thinks there are no tests. This is clearly wrong.

Digging through the [Eclipse source code for `JUnitLaunchShortcut`](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/plain/org.eclipse.jdt.junit/src/org/eclipse/jdt/junit/launcher/JUnitLaunchShortcut.java) (lines 160-191), I found this:

```
private void launch(Object[] elements, String mode) {
    try {
        IJavaElement elementToLaunch= null;

        if (elements.length == 1) {
...
        }
        if (elementToLaunch == null) {
            showNoTestsFoundDialog();
            return;
        }
```

It only works if you select *exactly one* test class.

The menu option visibility is controlled by the `org.eclipse.jdt.junit` plugin configuration ([`plugin.xml`](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/plain/org.eclipse.jdt.junit/plugin.xml)), and that has the same issue (lines 221-234):

```
<contextualLaunch>
    <enablement>
        <with variable="selection">
            <count value="1"/>
            <iterate>
                <adapt type="org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaElement">
                    <test property="org.eclipse.jdt.core.isInJavaProject"/>
                    <test property="org.eclipse.jdt.core.hasTypeOnClasspath" value="junit.framework.Test"/>
                    <test property="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.canLaunchAsJUnit" forcePluginActivation="true"/>
                </adapt>
            </iterate>
        </with>
    </enablement>
</contextualLaunch>
```

The `<count value="1"/>` bit in the beginning acts as a selector, and it means the same thing: you have to have *exactly one* item selected, or the menu item won't show up.

I think we have found the problem :)

I also checked the file history for both these, and they haven't been changed since September 2006. So if you managed to do this with a more recent version you most likely had some kind of plugin installed that let you do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run the tests for multiple projects in Eclipse, at least using the normal runners. There are, however a number of options:

1. Create an ant/maven script which runs everything
2. If you want to run your tests every time you save, you can use [Infinitest](http://infinitest.github.io/).

From the site of Infinitest:

> Infinitest is a Continuous Testing plugin for Eclipse and IntelliJ. Each time a change is made on the source code, Infinitest runs all the tests that might fail because of these changes.

Infinitest can potentially run all of the tests in all projects.

Answer (score 1):

Bizarrely, installing the C developer tools gives you a feature that lets you run multiple groups. See http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#HOWTO_use_C.2FC.2B.2B_Unit_Testing_Support